# print ckeditor content from mysql

Tags: php, printing, ckeditor, echo

I am trying to print my content from the `ckeditor` I uploaded to the `db`.
In the admin panel editing `ckeditor` it's normal,

but once I print it in the site via:

```
        <?if (!empty($show['participants'])){?>
           <Div class="participants">
                <?=$show['participants']?>
           </Div>
        <?}?>
```

It's echo the tags only:

```
<p><strong>אנדרס מוסטונן</strong>, מנצח (אסטוניה)<br><strong>קרן הדר,&nbsp;</strong>סופרן (ישראל)<br><strong>ארה סאל</strong>, בריטון (אסטוניה)<br><strong>מקהלת עמק חפר&nbsp;</strong><br><strong>מקהלה אסטונית</strong><br><br><br><strong>בתוכנית:</strong><br><strong>אורף</strong>: כרמינה בורנה<br><strong>יואב תלמי</strong>: אלגריה למיתרים, טימפני ואקורדיון</p>
```

Var dumped `$show`:

```
array(27) { ["id"]=> string(3) "432" ["code"]=> string(36) "63c8bc24-f730-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["name"]=> string(10) "הקיסר" ["title_short"]=> string(163) "מפגש ענקים - כריסטיאן יארווי ורומן רבינוביץ' בביצוע "הפנטסטית" של ברליוז ו"הקיסר" של בטהובן" ["title_long"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(29) "<p>&nbsp;</p>" ["participants"]=> string(612) "<p><strong>כריסטיאן יארווי</strong>,מנצח (אסטוניה)<br><strong>רומן רבינוביץ'</strong>, פסנתר (ישראל)<br><br><strong>בתוכנית:</strong><br><strong>בן חיים</strong>: "תרועה לישראל"<br><strong>בטהובן</strong>: קונצ'רטו לפסנתר מס' 5 – הקיסר<br><strong>ברליוז</strong>: סימפוניה פנטסטית<br><strong>ארוו פרט</strong>: Fratres</p>" ["image"]=> string(11) "keisarx.jpg" ["image_banner"]=> string(15) "julioskeiar.jpg" ["img_credits"]=> string(18) "בלש בורוץ'" ["video"]=> string(0) "" ["category_id"]=> string(2) "60" ["category_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_on_main"]=> string(1) "1" ["main_order"]=> string(1) "2" ["show_on_slide"]=> string(1) "0" ["slide_order"]=> string(1) "1" ["home_page"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(58) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/shows/הקיסר/events/1" ["english_name"]=> NULL ["english_direct_link"]=> NULL ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["update_auto_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-09-02 12:12:33" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_amfi_show"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_kunhiya_show"]=> string(1) "0" ["events"]=> array(3) { ["by_id"]=> array(2) { [1191]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1191" ["code"]=> string(36) "e7869a2b-ff30-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-07" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(43) "היכל התרבות ראשון לציון" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(99) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-7_20.00/היכל ראשון לציון/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3709" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } [1193]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1193" ["code"]=> string(36) "49a650f7-f630-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-09" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(71) "המשכן לאמנויות הבמה, בית האופרה תל אביב" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(88) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-9_20.00/בית האופרה/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3695" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["by_order"]=> array(2) { [0]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1191" ["code"]=> string(36) "e7869a2b-ff30-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-07" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(43) "היכל התרבות ראשון לציון" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(99) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-7_20.00/היכל ראשון לציון/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3709" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1193" ["code"]=> string(36) "49a650f7-f630-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-09" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(71) "המשכן לאמנויות הבמה, בית האופרה תל אביב" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(88) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-9_20.00/בית האופרה/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3695" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["by_date"]=> array(2) { ["2018-10-07"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1191" ["code"]=> string(36) "e7869a2b-ff30-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-07" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(43) "היכל התרבות ראשון לציון" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(99) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-7_20.00/היכל ראשון לציון/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3709" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["2018-10-09"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(20) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1193" ["code"]=> string(36) "49a650f7-f630-e811-bd2b-10604ba9908f" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-10-09" ["time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" ["show_id"]=> string(3) "432" ["venue_code"]=> NULL ["venue_name"]=> string(71) "המשכן לאמנויות הבמה, בית האופרה תל אביב" ["english_venue_name"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["english_city"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["english_country"]=> NULL ["start_sale_date"]=> NULL ["end_sale_date"]=> NULL ["direct_link"]=> string(88) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/he-IL/events/הקיסר/2018-10-9_20.00/בית האופרה/1" ["english_direct_link"]=> string(67) "http://tickets.isorl.co.il/loader.aspx/?target=hall.aspx?event=3695" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["update_timestamp"]=> string(19) "2018-08-09 12:52:29" ["is_for_sale"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_on_upcoming"]=> string(1) "0" } } } } }
```

What is going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please print the entire content of the `$show`?

Comment: @DavidWinder edited

Comment: Any one ? please..

Comment: It looks the same in your examples. Can you confirm that the db has the data correctly? Maybe try to check char coding on your sql connection too.

Comment: @Razor_alpha its the same .